# Using terraform to create an aggregate ethernet interface on paloalto?

Tags: terraform

I've been trying to get terraform to create a new ae interface with no luck.

My tf files are very basic working with a factory reset PA3020 that only has the user, password, and IP preconfigured.

It's connecting correctly as I've been able to create/modify other values such as a management profile.

Has anyone successfuly been able to create an aggregate group in paloalso using terraform? If so how was that done?

```
provider "panos" {
  hostname = "${var.pa-mgt-ip}"
  username = "${var.pa-username}"
  password = "${var.pa-password}"
}

resource "panos_ethernet_interface" "ae_int1" {
  name = "ae1"
  vsys = "vsys1"
  mode = "layer3"
  comment = "AE interface from TF"
}

resource "panos_ethernet_interface" "phy_int1" {
    name = "ethernet1/3"
    vsys = "vsys1"
    mode = "aggregate-group"
    aggregate_group = "${panos_ethernet_interface.ae_int1.name}"
    comment = "AE1 physical interface from TF"
}
resource "panos_ethernet_interface" "phy_int2" {
    name = "ethernet1/4"
    vsys = "vsys1"
    mode = "aggregate-group"
    aggregate_group = "${panos_ethernet_interface.ae_int1.name}"
    comment = "AE1 physical interface from TF"
}
```

The error is `ae1 'ae1' is not a valid reference` and the interface is not getting created. If I manually create the ae1 interface in the UI and set the group to ae1 in for the physical interfaces in the TF file they fail with the error `aggregate-group is invalid`.

Does panos not currently support creating AE interfaces? I couldn't find any issues in github related to creating interfaces.